# association or tagging for conception in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, tagging, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm facing a conception problem in developping a website for my videogame.
I have a Model named VideoLink which contain a title, a description and a link to a webvideo (for example youtube).
I have other models such as User, Map, Mission etc.
I want my users to be able to say that a video was made on those maps, during this mission, and those users appears.

I'm wondering if I should go with associations (with has_many relationships) or tagging (with acts_as_taggable_on and 3 attributes maps_list, users_list, mission).
I find associations a little heavy for this as it is a tagging thing not really a relation.
But maybe I'm wrong and tagging could not be the best choice.

Which solution you think is the most relevant to my situation ?
If you have other solutions or questions please tell me, I'm in fact a noob at ror ^^

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably get a lot more out if it using associations. If you want to do things like easily generating links to view more details about videolink resources, associations are definitely the way to go. You can do this without associations, but honestly it's a lot less trouble in the long-run if you simply throw a few associations into your models. You could probably build your own tagging solution more specific to your problem-domain easily if you have associations in place for all your models as well. I would recommend taking this option especially so if you're new to ruby on rails, as ActiveRecord associations are an integral part to RoR and it could be a great learning experience. Check out [Why associations?](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#why-associations) for a little more detail on how associations can be useful, the rest of the guide is also a must-read if you haven't already.

If you don't really see value in links and being able to easily query a video for related resources, go with acts_as_taggable_on.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I can still get a video for a Map with tagging right ? (like this : VideoLink.tagged_with(MAP_NAME)). In fact I was thinking of tags because I can't find a good has_many relationship. I learnt that we should always use has_many :through and for most case I can find the "middle class" but for example with VideoLink and Map I can't find one relevant, do you have any idea ?